# Does the wave equation require an initial function for one of its derivative?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Is it possible to find an explicit solution to the wave equation:
$$
\partial_t^2u-c^2 \partial_x^2 u=0
\\
u(x,0)=f(x), \ u(cx,x)=g(x)
$$
or do we need information about a derivative of $u$ as well?

Comment: so are you saying for the final condition that $t=x$ to prescribe the solution to be $g(x)$? A little strange to me.

Comment: Yeah, I am wondering if there is a typo and it should be $\partial_t u(cx,x)=g(x)$.  Because I am pretty sure that you need derivative information to solve a second order PDE.

Answer (score 2):

The method of solving is shown below. The solution is :
$$u(x,t)=f(x-ct)+g\left(\frac{x+ct}{2c}\right)-g\left(\frac{x-ct}{2c}\right)$$
So, the solution doesn't need more information to be determined.

[image]

Note : An obvious mistake in my first edition has been corrected.